# site: search on Google was showing results from another site, they were removed, but now reappeared in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, spam, negative-seo, url-removal

I'm facing an odd situation, I've added site as property to google search console in this april, around last week i checked that search query, site:my-site.com was showing links for pages which I have never created, they all had happening.pk title in it. Their cached version showed content from happening.pk and while I clicked on them, it goes to my site with 404 content not found. I requested google to remove all outdated pages [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1) and google approved the request.

Next day all weird search results were gone. Now google re crawled my site recently and I'm baffled to see that  all happening.pk results have reappeared. My host did checked for malware and says my site is clean, checked with sucuri, says its clean. Google doesn't have any manual or security action for me. In coverage in google tools I can see that there're more than 200 excluded pages with crawling date from January 2017 to May 2020. And I don't recogonize a single of them, all are happening.pk pages. I started creating my site from March 2020, moved to premium host in this May and  created site from scratch without migrating anything.

How do i get rid of these happening.pk search results for google search query, site:my-site.com. Also I can see that pages I published are appearing in google coverage but not in search results for site:my-site.com. Please guys provide some guidance.

**EDIT:**  these pages are visible in coverage under anomaly. Shows last crawled date for a particular page like my-site.com//uncategorized/bunvat-festival/
 Feb 2018 but I've removed this page two times in this month. For 404 pages crawl date was in may 2020. Under my coverage it says that URL might be known from other sources that are currently not reported. Another thing is my site is completely https whereas these urls are http: //www only, can it be possible that the source of these urls are not from my site.

Comment: Unrecognized pages on your site is almost always because of a hack.   How are you testing that those pages return 404?   Are you using "inspect URL" from Google Search Console?  If not, the malware may be showing itself only to Googlebot.

Comment: when I click the search result, my site says: It seems we can’t find what you’re looking for. Perhaps searching can help. Just looked in inspect url , google says for http property: URL is not on Google, its unknown to google. For https property, its says url not in property, switch proerties or inspect url from current property.

Comment: I've submitted a sitemap and urls are gone for now through same url removal request. Is it possible to make google crawl only pages from the sitemap. I've found that the last crawl date for these spam pages were before I moved to a new host. I hope that they don't reappear now. I've made a small edit to question as well.

Comment: Now use the "live test" in inspect URL.  That actually fetches the page from Google's datacenters as Googlebot.  That is the only way to detect if the hack is configured to show itself only to Googlebot.  You should also look back through your log files and see if Googlebot has gotten 200 status fetching those URLs in the past.

Comment: Sitemaps don't work to limit crawling.    To remove URLs from Google you need to make sure Googlebot gets a 404 error for them.

Comment: Thanks stephen, I checked live test , it says, failed , 404 not found and removal request is accepted as well. Tried to gleen  logs but it'll take some time for me to get used to of them, this was the first occasion for me to see how logs look like.